# How to use WebSocket class in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, websocket, xamarin.android

I want to write simple **WebSocket** client in Xamarin for Android. I read [xamarin websocket docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket/), but without examples i don't know how correct use this class. Can you hep me please? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the document : https://github.com/NVentimiglia/WebSockets.Pcl

Comment: @YorkShen, thanks But, is it not standart xamarin component?

Comment: As the document said, WebSockets.PCL is just a portable class library.

Comment: @YorkShen, i downloaded [this package](https://github.com/NVentimiglia/Websockets.PCL). How to properly add it to the Xamarin project?

Comment: You can add the WebSockets.PCL to your project by Nuget Packages.

Comment: @YorkShen, my_project -> add -> add nuget packages -> WebSockets.PCL Is not located int his place.

Comment: your project -> Manage Nuget Packages -> Brower -> WebSockets.PCL -> Install

Comment: @YorkShen, please, see [this](http://pho.to/Ak7Wc). My menu don't have Manage Nuget Packages.